# how to change my command prompt to show current working directory

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'm trying to change my command prompt to display my current working directory, but it doesn't work for me. I have tried putting this in my bash_profile which is in my home directory:

PS1='\h:\w$ '

PS1='\h:$PWD \u$ '

and my prompt does change but it just shows the same as I'm putting in so it doesn't recognize things like \h and \w i think?

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.6[image]

Comment: I suggest that you download and read- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/

Answer (score 5):

You are using `zsh` so the definition needs to go to `.zshrc` and it's slightly different (see `man zshmisc` for all options). The equivalent for `\h \w \$` in `zsh` is

```
PS1='%m %~%# '
```

- `%m` The hostname up to the first '.'.  An integer may follow the `%`  to  specify  how  many
  components of the hostname are desired.  With a negative integer, trailing components of
  the hostname are shown.
- `%~` Current  working  directory.   If  an  integer follows the `%`, it specifies a number of
  trailing components of the current working directory to show; zero means the whole path.
  If the current working directory  starts  with  `$HOME`,  that  part  is
  replaced  by a `~`
- `%#` A `#` if the shell is running with privileges, a `%` if not.

Comment: I didn't notice I was using zsh to begin with so thanks for that. I have tried putting PS1='%m %~%# ' into a file called .zshrc in my home directory but it still won't work..

Comment: @kippelicious If you enter it directly at the prompt, does it work?

Comment: no.. MacBook-Pro ~% is all i see..

Comment: @Kippelicious Unless I'm misunderstanding something, `~` is the shorthand for your user directory. `~/` refers to the same folder as `/Users/yourusername/`, and you can print your working directory at any point with `pwd`. Apologies if this is going above my head, and if what you're looking to have the full system path printed in place of the conventional `user@ComputerName ~`. I am unsure how to do that or why exactly you'd need to. Also, just ensuring you did `touch ~/.zshrc` after updating the file.

Comment: @Kippelicious Looks about right, that's what you would get with `\h \w \$` in `bash`: `MacBook-Pro`, is your hostname, `~` the current directory and `%` is the result of `%#` for a non-root user. What did you expect?

Comment: @hdixon Updating a file will already update the timestamp, no need to `touch` afterwards.

Comment: @nohillside you're right, it is working. wasn't thinking straight..

Comment: Can I print to `stdout` the current dir without the path, just the dir? I know `pwd`. `echo %` does not work

Comment: ok, answering my comment `basename \`pwd\``

Answer (score -1):

In my case it works if I insert the following the .zshrc (then source .zshrc):

```
PS1='%1~>'
```

in this was it only shows the current name of the directory (not the full path), here an example how it looks like:

```
Documents>
```

Comment: That isa part of the accepted answer. How does your answer differ?

Comment: It's a straight way to implement it with an example, it could be quite time saving and more intuitive. Should i add it just as a comment?